# Disable Google Anayltics cookie from being sent to cookie less domain

Tags: javascript, optimization, cookies, google-analytics, subdomain

To optimize my site i have set up a static subdomain for content such as images, css and javascript. How do i stop the google analytics tracking cookie from being sent to my static subdomain, but still to both example.com and www.example.com?

Have already looked through some of the documentation with no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have a cookie that gets sent to `www.example.com` and `example.com` but not `othersubdomain.example.com`.

You can in theory have a cookie that gets sent to `example.com` but not `subdomain.example.com`, but it doesn't work in IE.

This is why you should not use a no-www `example.com` address when you are planning on using subdomains with their own security context. It's best to have only one of `www.example.com` and `example.com` as the ‘proper’ URL anyway. So set up a redirect for `example.com` to go to `www.example.com`, and cookies won't be shared unless you deliberately set `domain=.example.com` on them.

Comment: for anyone interested the code for the redirect was
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]

and then in the google analytics script you need to put
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', "www.example.com"]);

Answer (score 3):

If you're having issues with Google Analytics creating a cookie for every domain, including your subdomain ones. Here's my solution that I've posted elsewhere on the subject.

---

By golly I think I've found a temporary solution to the broken code supplied by Google.

If you go into GA and get the non-async code and choose:

```
One domain with multiple subdomains
Examples:   apps.konoro.org
    store.konoro.org
    video.konoro.org
```

You'll see that it gives you a code sample with `.konoro.org`. Change that to `www.konoro.org` and all cookies will have: `.www.konoro.org` (with a dot in front of them).

Now if you go back to your Async code, there's only one difference apart from being Async. You need to put `['_setDomainName', 'www.konoro.org']`, as the second option rather than after `['_trackPageview']`.

For some reason, with this being the second option, it works fine.

My final code is:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(
    ['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1'],
    ['_setDomainName', 'www.konoro.org'],
    ['_trackPageview']
); 

(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script');
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    ga.setAttribute('async', 'true');
    document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(ga);
})();
```

Comment: Apparently it has to go second because the _trackPageview initiates tracking so you can no longer pass variables afterwards...